# Ionic project Basic Structure with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to the ionic, i started to learn ionic,i am trying to create structure for ionic, i have added the ionic links.I created the separate html files and module file and config files and all, actually i want to load the separate html file with links....i added the code bellow..

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="SomeApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>App</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<link data-require="ionic@1.0.0-beta.1" data-semver="1.0.0-beta.1" rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.13/css/ionic.css" />
<script data-require="ionic@1.0.0-beta.1" data-semver="1.0.0-beta.1" src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.13/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="Module.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Core/config.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Controllers/WorkCtrl.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ion-view></ion-view>
</body>
</html>
```

**Module.js**

```
var ionApp = angular.module("SomeApp",['ionic']);
```

**config.js**

```
ionApp.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url:'/Home',
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/Home/Home.html'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('Work', {
            url:'/Work',
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/Home/Work.html'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('Personal', {
            url:'/Personal',
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/Home/Personal.html'
                }
            }
        })
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/Home');
});
```

**home.html**

```
<ion-view>
<ion-content>
    <button ng-click="gotoWork()">Work</button>
    <button ng-click="gotoPersonal()">Personal</button>
    Hello
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**Work.html and personal.html**

```
//Some matter Here in about two html files...
```

**WorkCtrl.js**

```
ionApp.controller(function($scope,$location){
    $scope.gotoWork = function(){
        $location.path("/Work");
    };
    $scope.gotoPersonal = function(){
        $location.path("/Personal");
    };
});
```

I am trying to load first home.html file....but it is displaying just white page without any errors can u please reply any one if i did any wrong in this code..

Comment: how are you running this? If you use live reload, `ionic run <platform> -l -c -s`, is an error being thrown when trying to access `home.html`? Also make sure that your view is actual at the path `views/home/home.html`

Answer (score 0):

Can you write your folders structure? Are you sure to have the HTML file in a folder Home? I think that your tamplateUrl is not correct!

Comment: my folder structure is...   one folder is JS....inside js we have CONTROLLERS,CORE, in inside controllers folder we will write controller file and in core folder we will write config.js file...                                               second Folder is VIEWS, inside views we have another folder is home,in that we have home.html,personal.html,work.html.. files...            and index.html and Module.js files is outside...

Comment: You set the same lower or upper case name folder? The folder name is Home     or home?

Comment: My Folder name is Home

Comment: actually i added the <ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>, when i am adding this it is displaying the black screen and path is coming like bellow  http://127.0.0.1:50895/index.html#/Home

Comment: it is going to that screen but it is displaying black screen\

Comment: if u have mail please send me i will send code rar file

Answer (score 0):

Try :
.state('home', { url:'/Home',  templateUrl: 'views/Home/Home.html'  })

TemplateUrl in the same level of URL in the json when you set the state...

Comment: Home.html or home.html?

Comment: File name is Home.html

Comment: In the documentation ion-view is :     <ion-nav-view> <ion-view view-title="My Page"> <ion-content> Hello! </ion-content> </ion-view> </ion-nav-view>

Comment: Try to add ion-nav-view

Comment: i tried  <ion-nav-view> <ion-view view-title="My Page"> <ion-content> Hello! </ion-content> </ion-view> </ion-nav-view> this one it is woking but i want to load other file here

Comment: just i wrote <ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>  at that it is going to that page but displaying black screen

Comment: if u have mail please send me i will send code rar file